# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException in update/delete query

Tags: java, jpa, primefaces

I am working on a simple application where the records of users in a database are displayed in a primefaces datatable and the user can edit or delete the records.
Here is the jsf file

```
<h:form>
            <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userBean.users}" >
                <p:column headerText="username">
                    <h:inputText value="#{user.username}" rendered="#{userBean.editable}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" rendered="#{not userBean.editable}" />
                    <!--<h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />-->
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="edit">
                    <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{userBean.editAction(index)}" rendered="#{not userBean.editable}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="save">
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" id="save" disabled="false" action="#{userBean.saveAction(user)}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="delete">
                    <p:commandButton value="Delete" id="delete" disabled="false" action="#{userBean.deleteAction(user)}"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>
```

and here is the save and update action methods i am calling in the bean

```
public String saveAction(User user) {

    this.setEditable(false);
    DB db = new DB();
    db.updateUser(user);
    return "editSuccess";
}

public String deleteAction(User user) {

    DB db = new DB();
    db.deleteUser(user);
    return "editSuccess";
}
```

and here are the methods in the dao layer

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RegisterationFormJPAPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
public void updateUser(User user) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("update User set username = :uname where username = :uname");
    query.setParameter("uname", user.getUsername());
    query.executeUpdate();
}

public void deleteUser(User user) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("delete from User where username = :uname");
    query.setParameter("uname", user.getUsername());
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

But when i press the edit link or the delete button, this error appears

```
    Severe:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
```

Would anyone tell me where is the problem.

Comment: first this I would do is em.getTransaction().isActive() to see if really there is no active transaction. check this and update please

Comment: I wrote this line at the beginning of the updateUser(User user) method, 
"System.out.println("active "+em.getTransaction().isActive());", and it printed "active false" in the console.

Comment: ok this means that the transaction is not active so now we can concentrate on this, i told you to do this just to make sure.

Comment: Why not just call em.remove(user); and em.merge(user);?

Comment: I tried removing the user then merging it, but i got an exception. I think the cause of the exception is that the data base has an auto increment column which represents the user id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pleased try this:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
   Query query = em.createQuery("update User set username = :uname where username = :uname");
    query.setParameter("uname", user.getUsername());
    query.executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: It is solved for the deleteUser method and it deleted the user from the database, but in the updateUser method, the user is not updated in the database, knowing that i got this warning at the update query "Input parameters can only be used in where clause or having clause of a query".

Comment: this is very strange, but can you try to make the whole query one string, without the setParameter? The string whole me something like:
"update User set username = '" + user.getUsername() + "' where username = '" + user.getUsername() + "'";
also try createNativeQuery instead of createQuery

Comment: by the way it seems that you are not doing anything with query u set the username equal to the username if I am not mistaken :)

Comment: also how to you know that the user is not updated when you are not changing any values really? Try to switch jpa to print the queries executed and see if an update is being sent to the database

Comment: You are right :), the problem is in the query. When the save buyyon is pressed, the saveAction method is called with the user that i want to edit, but i need also to get the new user entered after pressing the Edit button, but i do not know how to get the new user, all i have now is the old user.
Do you know how to get the new user after editing?.
And thanks in advance :)

Comment: i can help you but please explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve. i am confused with the new and the old user

Comment: ok, now we have a datatable with a list of  user names where i got this list from the database, until now everything is ok.
Lets assume that we have a user with username "user1".
I have a column in the datatable with a link at each row to edit the user of that row, when you press the edit link, the field of the username become editable so that you can edit the user (let's say we edited it to "user2" instead of "user1"), then there is save button where i call the saveAction method with object of the user as parameter,

Comment: when i printed the user object that pass to the saveAction method, the old username (before editing which is "user1") is printed, although it is supposed that when i press the saveAction button that the bean is updated to the new user (after editing which is "user2"), but the old user ("user1") is printed.
The problem now is that i do not have the edited username (which is "user2"), all i have is the user object passed to the saveAction method which is always the old username ("user1 in our case"). How can i get the new username ("user2") in order to execute my query.

Comment: i separated the problem in two comments.

Comment: what you should do if i understand correctly is, change the button from edit to save and make it disabled, the time that the user enters value inside the textfield enable the save button. when the user presses the save buttong call the action and also pass the value of the textfield to the controller. with htis way you make sure that when the user presses the button there will be value. you understand me?

Comment: I solved the problem by using the datatable edit row in primefaces, i removed the view i have done and used the datatable-edit found [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) and it updated the database. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: no problem, always happy to assist. if you see in the link you sent me tha textfield becomes editable only after you press the edit button

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly call the transaction in this context. The commit is managed by the server automatically.

You can simply use:

```
user.setName("NEW USER NAME"); 
modifyUser(user); 

public void modifyUser(User user) {
     em.merge(user)}
```